# Any difference between those two in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Using this

```
var Class1 = function() {       
        this.test1 = function() {
        };
    };
```

---

and the following

```
function Class1() { 
};

Class1.prototype.test1 = function() {

};
```

Is there difference between those two?

Comment: This has been asked _so_ many times before...

Comment: Can a question be closed as duplicate to 2 questions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

The first one makes a separate copy of the function for each class instance.
It also allows the function to use closure'd variables from the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There is difference which affects performance as well.

The first one will add function to each instance of the created class while latter won't. For the latter method, JavaScript will look into `prototype` chain of the object and would return the needed method, the `test1` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are. See

- [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1048572) and
- [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/310870/1048572)

for the two (independent) differences.

Answer (score 0):

Using the later one in efficient.

Functions in JavaScript are objects. Every object in JavaScript holds a hidden piece of state – a reference to another object known as the object’s prototype.

Using prototype multiple objects can maintain references to the same prototype object.

This is a great [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff852808.aspx) to know how prototype in js works.